# How to separate two windows created with chrome extension with different identity so no cookies are shared between different identities

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, cookiestore

I am creating two windows with chrome extension using chrome. windows API. the problem is when I create the first window and I reach a payment web page on the first window some cookies are set, But after I create the second window and reached the same payment web page I get the same cookies which false one of the payments.

So I want different cookies should be created on different windows. I have seen it in firefox you can use contextual identities to separate identities in firefox. But how can we achieve such a thing in chrome?

Plz, help.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing cookies across all tabs and windows is common to Chrome, Firefox and Edge.
I wanted to test logging into by web site as two different people.
My solution was to log one user into Chrome and the second into Edge.
This works because Chrome and Edge do not share cookies.

Comment: but what about having different cookies in  separate windows of the same browser?

Comment: The browser would still transmit the cookies from all windows back to the server.  The server won't be able to tell which window the sent a particular cookie.